# repeating rnorm 20 times but not able to get 20 random outputs

Tags: r, loops, vector, random

I am currently programming a loop and have made a vector called `growth_rate`. I want to use the `rnorm` function to draw a random number for this vector 20 times. The code I am using to do this is

```
growth_rate <- rep((rnorm(n = 1, mean = 1, sd = 0.4)), times = 20)
```

I have also made a vector called

```
rate <- rnorm(n = 1, mean = 1, sd = 0.4)
```

Making a vector called

```
grate <- rep(rate, 20)
```

it still outputs the same number 20 times instead of 20 random numbers e.g.

> [1] 1.304936 1.304936 1.304936 1.304936 1.304936 1.304936 1.304936 1.304936 1.304936

and so on...

Is there anyway I can output 20 random numbers in one vector and not make 20 separate vectors using `rnorm` instead? Thank you!

Comment: Use `replicate` not `rep`.

Comment: I used >growth_rate<-replicate(rate, 20) and it returned only one output [1] 20. Could any one advise as I am a bit baffled..

Comment: @JohnL See my answer and explanation below.

Comment: replace 20 instead of 1 in n parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to draw 20 samples from the same normal distribution, just use `rnorm(20, ...)`.

```
set.seed(2017);
rnorm(20, mean = 1, sd = 0.4);
#[1] 1.1843665 0.4939755 0.7252589 0.8217352 1.4896327 1.1439255 1.1603086
#[8] 1.0442731 0.7776635 1.7147653 1.1991402 0.2133531 1.2805424 0.8108834
#[15] 0.5728705 0.9128100 0.5895982 0.7084435 0.7499843 0.3253227
```

In your approach, you first draw *one sample* from a normal distribution, and then replicate the *same number* 20 times.

Comment: how can I add each of these 20 rnorm samples to an individual year (between 1:20). I am writing a loop and its taking me longer than I thought it would :-/

Comment: @JohnL What do you mean by "add each of these [...] samples to an individual year"?

Comment: I am writing a loop that calculates the population size (starting from 1000) depending on growth rate over a period of 20 years. For each year I am using rnorm to try and obtain a random growth rate for my calculation. I am probably completely wrong in my methods of putting this loop together

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Do you want to draw 20 samples for every year, or do you want to draw 20 samples where each sample corresponds to one year? In my example above, you're drawing 20 i.i.d samples *from the same normal distribution*.

Comment: yes, I would like to draw 20 samples where each sample corresponds to one year in just one vector. I basically want to assign the 20 samples to 1:20 years

Comment: Can't you just do `cbind.data.frame(year = 1:20, growth_rate = rnorm(20, mean = 1, sd = 0.4))`?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I am working on a tricky loop that is testing my tiny knowledge of R . I will get there ! :-)

Comment: No worries @JohnL. Glad to help & good luck with your project!